# Are there limits to host-guest OS version compatibility in Docker?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

Docker allows the host Linux distribution to be different from the guest Linux distribution.

Are there limits to this compatibility? Could you run a recent Ubuntu guest in a host whose kernel is much older?

Comment: This is a good read: https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/container-image-host-guide-technology-detail

Answer (score 8):

> Docker allows the host Linux distribution to be different from the guest Linux distribution.

To make things clear, there is no guest Linux distribution when running a Docker container. The Docker container is not a Linux OS.

Docker images such as ubuntu, centos, ... are not operating systems. They are just images that "mimic" an OS distribution from the point that they have a very similar filesystem structure and tools available
that you typically find on an OS distro like Ubuntu or Centos. Those images do not have their own kernel packaged inside.

If you are wondering whether you can run the Docker image `ubuntu:16.04` on a machine with `ubuntu:14.04` the answer is yes. In addition, there shouldn't be any compatibility problems in general with other images.

Now since the kernel is not part of the image, it is possible to create a Docker image that would work on one kernel version and fail on another. For instance, you can request a system call that might not exist
in an older kernel version.

However, this problem is not caused by docker, but rather is a compatibility issue with the software running inside the container.

Finally, if you are running Docker on a machine you will at minimum have a kernel version of 3.10 which is not very old. So it is unlikely to encounter any such limitations.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 includes 30,000+ packages. Isn't it likely that at least some of them might take advantage of kernel features that weren't available in 14.04?

Comment: @MaxB I was also wondering the same thing. May I inquire if you have any further inputs or insights on this matter?